# Rotating bar magnet : current induced in circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

I don't think this problem makes sense. The answer given is (a). Aren't the field lines parallel to the loop, what does rotation affect ? create atomic currents?

Comment: The upper part of the loop, the one which is parallel to 'N' and is the topmost is perpendicular to the magnetic field lines due to 'N'. The rotating of the bar magnet would cause relative motion between that part of the loop and the magnetic field. In other words it should be something like rotating a conductor in a magnetic field...

Comment: In the configuration shown, how is the magnetic flux in the loop changing with time?

Comment: @DavidWhite Exactly. There is a slight possibility that the answer may be given incorrect. But I don't know.

Comment: @KunalPawar That is right, I've been rolling it out a little bit more.

Comment: @DavidWhite The magnetic field has a relatively movement to the charges in the horizontal part of the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnetic field from the bar magnetic could be represented by magnetic field lines. This lines outside the magnet are bended between the poles and by this they cross the wire in its horizontal part. Since the magnet is rotating the field lines one by one crossing the horizontal part of the electrical circuit.

Now remember the **Lorentz force** $$\vec F = q \vec v \times \vec B $$

If a moving charge (an electron) goes through an external magnetic field (non-parallel to this magnetic field) then the charge gets deflected (perpendicular to the plane made by the electrons movement direction and the external magnetic field).

The Lorentz force is one of the three possibilities between the constituents magnetic field, relatively movement between this field and a charge and the reflection of the charge. Beside the Lorentz force the other phenomena are called **induction of a current** and **induction of a magnetic field**.

Due to [this source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1219127/1616) the vector product from perpendicular vectors can be rewritten to
 $$ q \vec v = \dfrac {(\vec B \times \vec F)}{\|\vec {B}\|^2} $$
This is an equation that helps to understand that a current flows in the circuit and ***the answer is a)***.

For more details see on Wikipedia about the [Homopolar generator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_generator):

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you are imagining "a moving field"? And the force you have used in the $ q \vec{v} $, how do you imagine it? How do you infer that the current was dc?

Comment: **Moving field:** It's enough to have a relatively movement between the wire and the magnetic field, so you can rotate or the wire around the magnet or the bar magnet. More than this, a changing magnetic field strength with both the source and the electron in rest to each other will induce a current too. **Force in equation 2:** Even if the friction is neglected the rotating bar magnet came to standstill because the work done for the current has to come from something (the kinetic energy of the rotating bar).

Answer (score 3):

The trick in such a problem is visualization. There is an emf between the two points of connection. There are a lot of ways to attack this and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_paradox) Wikipedia page is very illuminating. Personally, I like to imagine a moving rod or a line segment that cuts through the magnetic field, which is seen as stationary and constant.

Now, there is a horizontal as well as a vertical distance between the points of connection. The vertical distance is along the magnetic field lines, so it does not cut through them. However, the horizontal distance does cut between the lines.
[image]
[image]

Now, the horizontal emf is, as detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_paradox#Use_of_special_techniques_with_Faraday.27s_law), just $\frac{d\phi}{dt}=B\frac{dA}{dt}=B\frac{d\theta}{dt2\pi}*\pi R^2=B\omega \frac{R^2}{2}$, which is constant. So there is a DC current.

I highly recommend reading that Wikipedia page.