# Deflection of moving charges through a homogeneous magnetic field: Relative movement to which structure?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin, electromagnetic-induction

For this question [Rotating bar magnet : current induced in circuit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318273/rotating-bar-magnet-current-induced-in-circuit) I gave a comment

> It's enough to have a relatively movement between the wire and the magnetic field, so you can rotate or the wire around the magnet or the bar magnet. More than this, a changing magnetic field strength with both the source and the electron in rest to each other will induce a current too.

Thinking about this I came in trouble. With a changing magnetic field strength it's all ok. There is a gradient of the field strength and - to use an analogy - a marble will follow this gradient, say an inclination or an inhomogeneous friction resistance. But what is about the relative motion of a charge through a homogeneous magnetic field. The gradient of the field strength is zero. Using again the analogy, there isn't any inclination nor an inhomogeneous friction.

So the question occurs how an electron gets deflected sideways in an "amorphous" field? Every idea of an analogy or an explanation is welcome.

Comment: A changing field strength implies that the temporal derivative is zero, not that the spatial derivatives are zero. The field could change in time such that the spatial derivatives all remained zero. Also, what is meant by "field strength?" By this, do you just mean the magnitude of the field? Since B is a vector, it doesn't have a gradient, although its components do. There is an object conventially called the "field strength tensor," but you have the same issue there. A marble rolling down a gradient just isn't a good analogy here.

Comment: If you really want to go with the marble thing, then you can boost into the rest frame of the electron, where the force due to the interaction with the magnetic field is zero. Then, there will be only an electric field, which is indeed a gradient of the potential, and which the electron will follow (backward, because of its negative charge). I don't feel like this is really an answer to your question, though.